# Socket id of socket.io hash can have commas?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using socket.io library over Node. I want to split by commas a string have different hash (socket id) of same user, this solution is broke if hash of socket ID have commas.

For example i want to save this string:

```
username@email.com:xlCGTJrldYLAs8eoAAAD,nLS5Avb1WHdwarrjAAAC
```

If socket ID hash have a comma, split function not work

Edited:

My code:

```
var s = "username@email.com:xlCGTJrldYLAs8eoAAAD,nLS5Avb1WHdwarrjAAAC"
var dd = s.split(":");
dd[1].split(",");
//result ["xlCGTJrldYLAs8eoAAAD", "nLS5Avb1WHdwarrjAAAC"]
```

This code work great, but if socket.io hash for ID have ":" or "," my code break
Thanks !!

Comment: I'm afraid your question is not clear at all. Who/what generates this string? What are you trying to split, with what code, what are you expecting, and what are you getting?

Comment: thanks for comment. I generate the string for save all socket id conections. i try to split all after ":"

Comment: You're not answering half of the questions.

Comment: i edited my questin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

socket.io ids as generated by socket.io will not contain a comma unless you are using a namespace with a comma in it.

To understand what they can contain, one needs to look at the socket.io code to see how the id is generated.  While socket.io is built in many different layers in several repositories (which makes sleuthing through the code somewhat difficult), the id generation follows this path:

In [engine.io/server.js on line 281](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io/blob/master/lib/server.js#L281):

```
var id = this.generateId(req);
```

And, then the [genereateId method](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io/blob/master/lib/server.js#L281):

```
Server.prototype.generateId = function (req) {
  return base64id.generateId();
};
```

And, [`base64id.generateId()`](https://github.com/faeldt/base64id/blob/master/lib/base64id.js) returns a base64 encoded value.  And, the [base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) itself does not include a comma.

So, you can conclude that the core part of the id value generated by socket.io will not have a comma in it.

There is socket.io code that can add the namespace and a hash value to the beginning of the id as [shown here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L64):

```
this.id = nsp.name !== '/' ? nsp.name + '#' + client.id : client.id;
```

where `client.id` is the id generated in the previous code by `base64id.generateId()`.

If you are not using a namespace with a comma in it, then the socket.id should not contain a comma.  If you are using a namespace with a comma in it, then the `socket.id` will likely contain a comma.